# How to get webform title and category with no submissions in view or hook?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I have a survey form created with webform module. I have to display all survey form title with submissions and without submissions with webform category on home page. But it displaying only submitted survey forms title. How can I display webform title with zero submission in drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code as a function  in your module file and call it on your custom block.

```html
function module_name_webformtitle(){
  $query = Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('webform');
  $query->condition('category', 'survey_name');//your survey name
  $entity_ids = $query->execute();
  $webform_id=array();
  foreach($entity_ids as $webid){
    $webform_id[]=$webid;     
  }

  $webform = Webform::loadMultiple($webform_id);
   foreach($webform as $webforms){
            $webformtitle=$webforms->get('title');
        }


  }
```